# Best way to handle functions and sub functions

Tags: python

What is the 'Pythonic' way to handling functions and using subfunctions in a scenario where they are used in a particular order?

As one of the ideas seem to be that functions should be doing 1 thing, I run into the situation that I find myself splitting up functions while they have a fixed order of execution. 
When functions are really a kind of 'do step 1', 'then with outcome of step 1, do step 2' I currently end up wrapping the step functions into another function while defining them on the same level. However, I'm wondering if this is indeed the way I should be doing this.

Example code:

```
def step_1(data):
    # do stuff on data
    return a

def step_2(data, a):
    # do stuff on data with a
    return b

def part_1(data):
    a = step_1(data)
    b = step_2(data, a)

    return a, b

def part_2(data_set_2, a, b):
    # do stuff on data_set_2 with a and b as input

    return c
```

I'd be calling this from another file/script (or Jupyter notebook) as part_1 and then part_2
Seems to be working just fine for my purposes right now, but as I said I'm wondering at this (early) stage if I should be using a different approach for this.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can use a Class here, otherwise your code can be made shorter using the following:

```
def step_1(data):
    # do stuff on data
    return step_2(data, a)

def step_2(data, a):
    # do stuff on data with a
    return a, b

def part_2(data_set_2, a, b):
    # do stuff on data_set_2 with a and b as input

    return c
```

Comment: thinking about scheduling and kicking of tasks in a pipeline/dataflow I figured the 'part_1' made sense as I don't need to kick off step_1 without step_2... so instead of kicking them both off I can just start part_1
and I need to do this multiple times as well, so it saves code/management when executing the different steps

Answer (score 0):

As a rule of thumb, if more functions use the same arguments, it is a good idea to group them together into a class. But you can also define a `main()` or `run()` function that makes uses of your functions in a sequential fashion. Since the example you have made is not too complex, I would avoid using classes and go for something like:

```
def step_1(data):
    # do stuff on data
    return step_2(data, a)

def step_2(data, a):
    # do stuff on data with a
    return a, b

def part_2(data_set_2, a, b):
    # do stuff on data_set_2 with a and b as input
    return c


def run(data, data_set_2, a, b):
    step_1(data)
    step_2(data, a)
    part_2(data_set_2, a, b)

run(data, data_set_2, a, b)
```

If the code grows in complexity, using classes is advised. In the end, it's your choice.